# Contact company before sending an application?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, applications

I'm from Germany and i'll be looking for a job (software developer) in Belgium later this year (Flanders area like Gent, Antwerp, Bruges).
My English is fluent but i don't speak a word of Flemish.
Many jobs i found require both languages even though the job offer is written in English.

Would it be wise to contact the companies before writing an application to ask if they accept English only speaking applicants or if they offer something like a language course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send your application and get no feedback you won't know if it's because of you not being able to speek Flemish or something else.

If I were you I will simply ask this question:
 1. Trying to ask recruiter by email or LinkedIn
 2. Trying to call the company so as to ask someone
 3. Sending my application anyway
 4. Trying to reach someone again so as to explain the situation

Do not be discouraged by not having a straight answer (or an answer at all) recruiter might be really busy (despite what you heard ^^)

Do not wait so long before calling them to have your answer and do not hesitate to send your application in the meantime, it would be a shame being late for this application just because of this missing information.

Best of luck ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would simply apply and see what happens. If they're not interested in you they simply won't call you.

Some companies may be willing to give you a chance to learn the language.